# Avoiding page reload after redirect

Tags: javascript, polymer

Using Polymer 0.4.2 & [app-router](http://erikringsmuth.github.io/app-router/).

This is my routing table

```
 <app-router>

    <app-route path="/" import="landing/landing-page.html"></app-route>

    <app-route path="/balance" import="balance/balance-view.html"></app-route>
    <app-route path="/balance/:year/:month" import="balance/balance-view.html"></app-route>
    <app-route path="/balance/:year/:month/:day" import="balance/day-view/day-view.html"></app-route>

    <app-route path="*" import="landing/landing-page.html"></app-route>

</app-router>
```

When `/balance` is called, I need to determine the current year & month and do a redirect to `/balance/year/month`. I have tried both `router.go()` and `window.location` to do this redirect.

If I do so, the `balance-view` component will get included a second time below the first instance, causing the layout to break. The only way I currently see to fix that is `window.location.reload()`. However, this causes a nasty delay in the applications flow.

Where lies the issue & how can it be solved?

Answer (score 1):

After some struggling, I got it working:

Same `app-router` conf:

```
 <app-router>

  <app-route path="/" import="landing/landing-page.html"></app-route>

  <app-route path="/balance" import="balance/balance-view.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/balance/:year/:month" import="balance/balance-view.html"></app-route>
  <app-route path="/balance/:year/:month/:day" import="balance/day-view/day-view.html"></app-route>

  <app-route path="*" import="landing/landing-page.html"></app-route>

</app-router>
```

And then, in `balance/balance-view.html` :

```
<polymer-element name="balance-view" attributes="year month">
  <template>
    <h1>Balance view</h1>
    <h2>Year: {{year}}</h2>
    <h2>Month: {{month}}</h2>
  </template>
  <script>   
    Polymer("balance-view", {
      domReady: function() {
        console.log(this.pathArg1);
        if (this.year === undefined) {
          var d = new Date();
          var month = new Array();
          month[0] = "January"; month[1] = "February"; month[2] = "March"; month[3] = "April";
          month[4] = "May"; month[5] = "June"; month[6] = "July"; month[7] = "August";
          month[8] = "September"; month[9] = "October"; month[10] = "November"; month[11] = "December";
          var currentYear =  d.getFullYear();
          var currentMonth = month[d.getMonth()];
          document.querySelector('app-router').go('/balance/'+currentYear+'/'+currentMonth);
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

In the `domReady` fuction, if I detect that no `year` has been passed, I calculate the current year and month and I do:

```
document.querySelector('app-router').go('/balance/'+currentYear+'/'+currentMonth);
```

You can see it running in [this Plunker](http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/gFcztj8hfUwRnsXFjCAI/), the code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/gFcztj8hfUwRnsXFjCAI).

Hope it helps!